# Reset default zooming and navigator in Highcharts (ng-highcharts).

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm using stock chart of ng-highcharts. Here the available default zooming levels are `1m`, `3m`, `1y`, `YTD` and `All`. I want to achieve three things.

1. **Three more zooming** level like `3Y`, `5y`, `6Y`. And I want to **set one of them before drawing**.
2. **Disable input date field** at the top right corner. (dates can be changed while navigator is moving, but can't edit directly).
3. **Disable navigator** from **expanding and contracting**. (basically the size should be same as what is set by the zooming button).

Answer for at least any one of them is appreciable. Thanks in advance

Comment: 3) Do you mean that Navigator should disable "handles" events?

Comment: Yes disable handles events

Comment: At this moment this modification requires to wrap the scroller.prototype.init method and remove events on handlers inside the scroller.mouseDownHandler.

Comment: hello, did you got any solution for 3rd question?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it's been 3 years and I don't remember what I did there :/

Answer (score 1):

1)
Define the button in the rangeSelector object, like in default Highcharts.

```
    buttons: [{
      type: 'month',
      count: 1,
      text: '1m'
    }, {
      type: 'month',
      count: 3,
      text: '3m'
    }, {
      type: 'month',
      count: 6,
      text: '6m'
    }, {
      type: 'ytd',
      text: 'YTD'
    }, {
      type: 'year',
      count: 1,
      text: '1y'
    }, {
      type: 'year',
      count: 3,
      text: '3y'
    }, {
      type: 'year',
      count: 5,
      text: '5y'
    }, {
      type: 'year',
      count: 6,
      text: '6y'
    }, {
      type: 'all',
      text: 'All'
    }]
```

2) 
Set the `rangeSelector.inputEnabled` param as false,

Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/1689rfg2/

Comment: Thank you. Its working.. But for question number 2 I want that input field there. but non editable. anyway fixed that with css